# JavaScript change the Source of an Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to replace an image trough JavaScript. What I have right now is this HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 " id="demo3">
    <input type="image" src="intro.jpg" width="600px" onclick="gamepaper();" />
</div>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
document.write("<input type='image' src='intro-win.jpg' width='600px' />");
```

Now the problem is, that this image is now on a new page and doesn't replace the old image.

I have thought of making a function like this one:

```
function changeSource() {
    var image = document.querySelectorAll("img")[0];
    var source = image.src = image.src.replace("placeholder.png","01.png");
};
```

But this didn't work too.

Comment: try with this. $("demo3 input").attr('src', 01.png);

Comment: just out of curiosity, why an input-element for an image ?

Comment: Because it is also a button. But you're right, after the replacement of the image, it shouldn't be a button anymore.

Comment: @Marimba Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes. I've now solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `input` tag:

```
function changeSource() {
    var image = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];
    var source = image.src = image.src.replace("placeholder.png","01.png");
};
```

But a better way is to add an ID and target it:

```
document.write("<input type='image' src='intro-win.jpg' width='600px' id='MyImg' />");

function changeSource() {
    var source = MyImg.src = MyImg.src.replace("placeholder.png","01.png");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using `input type image` in your html, but in your `js` you are searching for `img`. This should be like the following:

```
var image = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=image]")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give an Id to your image and then use that id on document.ready function and change the source like this.

```
<div class="col-md-4 " id="demo3">
    <input id="myImage" type="image" src="intro.jpg" width="600px" onclick="gamepaper();" />
</div>
```

On Next Page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myImage').attr("src", "myOtherSource.jpg");
});
```

Comment: jQuery != JavaScript